# How to draw four graph by using one .csv file

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, graph, mschart

I want to draw four graph in one windows form in C# by using one .CSV file.
After binding data of .CSV file how can I implement my code to assign value to X and y axis.
There are 2 y axis like voltage(y1 axis) current(y2 axis) and Date is get x axis.

Please give me a help to over come this.
My code is following. But this code is not get correct data.

```
chart1.DataSource = ObservingData;
chart1.Series["Voltage"].XValueMember = "Date";

chart1.Series["Voltage"].YValueMembers = "AvE1";
chart1.Series["Current"].XValueMember = "Date";
chart1.Series["Current"].YValueMembers = "AvI1";
this.chart1.Titles.Add("Channel 1");   // Set the chart title
chart1.Series["Voltage"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;  // Set chart type 
chart1.Series["Current"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;  // Set chart type 

chart2.DataSource = ObservingData;
chart2.Series["Voltage"].XValueMember = "Date";
chart2.Series["Voltage"].YValueMembers = "AvE2";
chart2.Series["Current"].XValueMember = "Date";
chart2.Series["Current"].YValueMembers = "AvI1";
this.chart2.Titles.Add("Channel 2");   // Set the chart title
chart2.Series["Voltage"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;  // Set chart type 
chart2.Series["Current"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

chart3.DataSource = ObservingData;
chart3.Series["Voltage"].XValueMember = "Date";
chart3.Series["Voltage"].YValueMembers = "Av3";
chart3.Series["Current"].XValueMember = "Date";
chart3.Series["Current"].YValueMembers = "AvI1";
this.chart3.Titles.Add("Channel 3");   // Set the chart title
chart3.Series["Voltage"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;  // Set chart type 
chart3.Series["Current"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

chart4.DataSource = ObservingData;
chart4.Series["Voltage"].XValueMember = "Date";
chart4.Series["Voltage"].YValueMembers = "AvE4";
chart4.Series["Current"].XValueMember = "Date";
chart4.Series["Current"].YValueMembers = "AvI1";
this.chart1.Titles.Add("Channel 4");   // Set the chart title
chart4.Series["Voltage"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;  // Set chart type 
chart4.Series["Current"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Comment: __'Not correct' is not a useful problem desription!__ Please explain what is shown and what is wrong about it. Also explain the nature of the data, esp. the __data types__. Including a __screenshot__ is most useful for chart questions.. Also: Why not reduce the question to __one__ of the charts?

Comment: Sir please give me a solution for this.I already chart1.DataSource = ObservingData; bind the data.I want to know in here i call separately to the chart one by one.then after one time access data second graph can't get data.So I ask to give me a solution.please.And how I add y2 axis to chart.please help me